# Last Column of a dataGrid appears on resizing [lastColumn-1]

Tags: wpf

I was trying for a few hours to get rid of a "ghost" column that appear on my last Grid when I try to resize it. I know how not to display it, but every time I try to resize it the "unwanted" column appears from nowhere. Is there any solution to keep my [last-1] column resizable (I mean not to use CanUserResize="False") and last column hidden or not to appear when a resize [last-1] column is made?Many Thanks

Because Two DataGrid’s are aligned every time I resize the column of the first DataGrid I receive a space: [image: DataGrid]

Here is the XAML. Line 80 solved my problem but then I have other: user can not resize the column obviously
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have posted Xaml of your UI would have helped a lot to understand what's wrong. However these are settings I have on the DataGrid and do not get any extra column.

> Most important setting is ColumnWidth="*"

```
<DataGrid
            x:Name="grdSimpleMap"
            Margin="2"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            ColumnWidth="*"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Map}"
            >
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you but for the moment is not solving my issue. I edit the question again with XAML. Here is a good example of what I mean with resizing the last column:   
 (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-datagrid-selected-item-in-wpf-with-mvvm-pattern-using-blend-for-vis/).

Comment: @Little_quitty I am not sure but can you try to set the parent Grid Column Width to Auto and add ColumnWidth=* to DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution to keep my [last-1] column resizable (I mean not to use CanUserResize="False") and last column hidden or not to appear when a resize [last-1] column is made?

If you want to be able to resize the last column to a smaller width without having an "extra" column to fill the remaining space, you need to shrink the total width of the `DataGrid` when resizing. You can do this by setting its `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Left`:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" ...
```

Comment: Thank you but for the moment is not solving my issue.

Comment: Why not? And what does "for the moment" mean?